# jQuery iPhone Effect SlideLeft and SlideRight

Tags: jquery, slider

I would like to create the iPhone sliding effect that work like this way:

When the button is clicked the current div#1 will be sliding out to the left and hide itself while another div#2 will be sliding from the right and move to the location of of the previous slided out div.

And when the button is trigger again the div#2 will be sliding out to right while the previously hide div#1 will be sliding out from left.

I have try to use the code suggested by one of the user in stackoverflow but i just fail to get it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/qSvDz/

Could anyone pls guide me through it.

Thanks
Fire

Answer (score 3):

use this: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
with "scrollLeft" or "scrollRight" effect

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qSvDz/231/

The CSS just pushes #member-home off-screen while #home is on the screen. Fairly basic.

The button calls toggleDivs() every time it's clicked.
toggleDivs() grabs the two separate divs and assigns them to local variables.
First, it checks if the div #home is off-screen (position().left < 0). If so, it will pull it back on-screen by setting the CSS: `left: 0px` and push div #memberHome off-screen with the CSS `left: "-" + $home.width() + "px"`.
If not, then it will pull div #memberHome onto the screen `left: 0px` and push div #home off-screen `left: "-" + $home.width() + "px"`

```
function toggleDivs() {
    var $home = $("#home");
    var $memberHome = $("#member-home");
    if ($home.position().left < 0) {
        $home.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
        $memberHome.animate({
            left: "-1000px"
        });


    }
    else {
        $home.animate({
            left: "-" + $home.width() + "px"
        });
        $memberHome.animate({
            left: "0px"
        });
    }
}

$("button").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
});
```

Comment: Hi Jon, basically I would like the effect to be something like the tree slider effect in the github when performing folder browsing. You could check it out at https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider.

Comment: Hi Jon, thx for the fast reply. Basically I would like the effect to be something like the tree slider effect in the github when performing folder browsing. You could check it out at https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider.